# Make transaction feeless solidity 0.8.0

Tags: solidity

I am trying to reward a user for typing a review:

```
function addReview(..., address payable _to) external payable {
    ... // code for adding a review including check for reentrency attacks
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value + 1);
}
```

This throws an "internal contract error". Using Ganache, MetaMask, Solidity 0.8.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I want to transfer the funds from the smart contract's address.

Tried: using the Feeless library, using refundGasCost modifier (most of it was deprecated and failed when trying to fix).

**EDIT:**

This is my frontend code that calls this function:

**App.js**

```
addReview = (id, name, description, rating, codeToSubmit, timeAdded, account) => {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        this.state.review.methods.addReview(id, name, description, rating, codeToSubmit, timeAdded, account).send({ from: this.state.account }).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
            this.setState({ loading: false })
        })
    }
```

Comment: The code posted works without issues. The error should be in the code that wasn't shared.

Comment: You're actually right. Apologies for that. The code indeed doesn't give any errors. However, it doesn't "refund" the user's fees. 

The error is actually thrown when I attempt to fully refund with the additional gas fees (which I remember being 29700 from some other posts). Therefore I'm trying to transfer ```msg.value + 297000```. I will edit my question now

Comment: The transferred ethers are are from the contract balance. If it doesn't have enough for the `msg.value + 297000` it will revert.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to set it to 1 instead of 29700, and it still throws an error. I edited my question to include the frontend code. The error is thrown by MetaMask. It lets me confirm the transaction when I see a red ALERT, then after I confirm the transaction it gets reverted as you already suspected.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with ```transfer``` being deprecated in sol 0.8.0, but I'm not entirely sure, hence the question

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is just 1 wei, if the **contract** doesn't have enough ether to return to the sender it will revert.

Comment: How do I handle the contract's ETH balance? Can't I just assign an account from Ganache for the contract? For instance, the address from which I deploy?

Comment: To send ether to a contract it has to implement a [receive function](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/contracts.html#receive-ether-function). To withdraw from a contract it has to implement a function to perform the transfer or else ethers will be blocked in the contract.

Comment: As I understand, the ```payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value + 1);``` piece of code sends ETH from the contract to the user. I have a receive function ```receive() external payable { }```. How do I actually send ether to a contract? I looked it up on these forums and just don't see a concrete way to do it in Solidity

Comment: To fund a contract you have to make a transfer from your account to the contract address. It is not possible for contract to access funds from other address.